# How can a tmpfs folder in Docker be mounted and shared on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, python-multiprocessing

My application is utilizing `python` `multiprocessing.shared_memory`. On Linux, a `tmpfs` folder is created as the `/dev/shm` folder for `shared_memory`. In order to share memory between processes and containers, those other processes and containers would need access to `/dev/shm`.

If I have `docker` containers running on `Windows`, I would need to mount the `/dev/shm` container to Windows to allow the processes/containers to read shared memory.

On a `linux` system, I could just create a `tmpfs` mounting point and share like that I believe.

But on `windows`, what effect would mounting a `tmpfs` folder to a `Windows` folder have?

Some thoughts:

- Is mounting a Linux `tmpfs` folder to `Windows` possible at all?
- Would the contents of `/dev/shm` be transferred to `Windows` persistent storage successfully? This would involve a considerable performance hit (going from RAM to HDD).
- Is there some other mechanism by which I could mount/share the `/dev/shm` folder between `docker` and `Windows` to provide optimal performance?

I hope my explanation was logical. I'm new to these concepts and would appreciate guidance on this. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can even do that on Linux.  How would you do it?

Comment: I could be wrong. I just thought that going from Docker tmpfs to Linux tmpfs would be fine. I'm a beginner and these concepts are new, so perhaps that is wrong.

Comment: Maybe, but how would you refer to it?  If you need to communicate across different machines and virtual machines, you'll need to think about using TCP instead of shared memory.

Comment: This article says it can be done, but the example is Linux: https://datawookie.dev/blog/2021/11/shared-memory-docker/

Comment: I see what you mean. thanks for the input.